# Whats happen with the magento2-samples repo on Github?

Tags: magento2

I am confused. What happen with the Repo magento2-samples on Github?

Comment: what are facing now?

Comment: The repo can´t be called. If i call the old Repo URI there is a 404.

Comment: Can u please  update ur repo url `https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data`

Comment: This repo i know too. But i didn´t mean this. I mean the repo with the sample implementations like the payment gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a forked version if anyone needs it, it is around 10 months old - https://github.com/BenSpace48/magento2-samples

Magento have decided to close the samples repository for a while, the impression I get is they don't want to spend time updating them so they'd prefer the community to do it.

Quote from a member of staff from Magento:

> Sadly, we will no longer be able to link to the sample extensions, as
>   the decision was made to close the repository for now, until the 20+
>   extensions there can be systematically updated and tested with the
>   latest versions of Magento.

[Source](https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/1133)

### Update

They're back with an out of date disclaimer - https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information.
I am sadly to read this.
But thank you for the link. I bookmark it.

Comment: It sounds like they're now looking for someone to maintain it, so if someone/some people do come forward then it may be back.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples gives a 404.

I do not know an official answer, but my guess is that they were pulled (at least temporarily) because they do not demonstrate current best practices, or are not up to date with architectural changes: Not doing things the way they're meant to be done.